# How to persist Session in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Struggling to find a question which answers this as everybody else it trying to do more complicated things which turn out to be the issue.

I am using MVC C# and trying to set an ID (int32) in the session. Then all the other pages are checking if its there, and redirecting to the login if it isnt.

Seems that the session is not persisting at all though. As soon as I exit the method it thinks its a new session with no keys. Can anybody say why?

```
        // ATTEMPT: To Login to the Service
        Tuple<bool, string, Group> LoginResult = loginService.GetGroupByGroupCode(groupCode);

        if (LoginResult.Item1 == true)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["groupID"] = LoginResult.Item3.GroupID;
            Response.Redirect("/about");
        }
```

On the other controller (which is redirected to) I am reading the session value like this.

```
int GroupID = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["groupID"]);
```

Comment: how do you read the value from `Session`?

Comment: Hi Igor, updated post with how its reading the value

Comment: Why are you using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` instead of just `Session`?

Comment: @m-albert If he is in a secondary class, that isn't controller facing then he may not be using `System.Web`.

Comment: Are you creating the session from the controller?

Comment: @Tom McClean: is the session cookie set in the browser at all prior to calling this action?  I believe issuing a redirect would cause the client to try the redirect with the same request headers (generally speaking of course with certain conditions including browser behavior).  And if this action is the first time a client hit your site, then the session cookie wouldn't have been "set" on their end yet.